# My Else cout displays even if input is correct

Tags: c++

***Even i type Pythagoras or Probability it still displays my else output "topic not supported" how do i fix this?***

```
search = "Pythagoras";
pos = sentence.find(search);
if (pos != string::npos)                        
    cout << "pythagoras entry" << endl;
search = "Probability";
pos = sentence.find(search);
if (pos != string::npos)
    cout << "probability entry" << endl; 
else
    cout << "topic not supported" << endl;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: btw: you dont have to put the comlete output in a single line. Just as you do formatting via `\n` for the user of your code you should make the code readable for someone reading the code. ...btw2: you dont need to include that text in your question at all to demonstrate the problem, a short `cout << "1\n";` would suffice

Comment: Okay thanks for your help, sorry i'm new to this website! so there are no obvious problems with my code?

Comment: The `else` only applies to the second `if` statement.  So if "Probability" is not found, it will always print "Topic not supported..." even if "Pythagoras" *was* found.

Comment: That's what i figured, how would i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your sentence contains "Pythagoras", it will pass through the first **if**(outputting what's there), and then go on the "else" check for "Probability" - you don't break the execution after you found "Pythagoras" in the sentence, it will go for the second **if**, outputting what's in the "topic not found", because "Probability" != "Pythagoras". If you put "Probability" in the sentence, "topic not found" should NOT be outputted, unless you didn't show us the code you're actually using.

To fix this, I suggest using a boolean flag, something like

```
bool flag = false;
search = "Pythagoras";
pos = sentence.find(search);
if (pos != string::npos)                    
{
    cout << "pythagoras" << endl;
    flag = true;
}
search = "Probability";
pos = sentence.find(search);
if (pos != string::npos)
{                    
    cout << "probability" << endl; 
    flag = true;
}

if (!flag)
    cout << "not supported" << endl;
```

Comment: @James941 Make sure to upvote and accept the answer if you think that it is satisfying :)